# Call multiple Stored procedures with php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am using PDO to access my database, and I have there two stored procedures.
Right now, I execute to call to the procedures, which is working fine, something like this:

```
$q = $db->prepare("CALL sp1();");
$q->execute;
//parsing results here...

$q->closeCursor(); 

$q2 = $db->prepare("CALL sp2();");
$q2->execute;
///parsing results here...
```

I want to call both procedures in one prepare, so I tried something like -

```
$q = $db->prepare("CALL sp1(); CALL sp2()");
$q->execute;
```

But this is calling and executing only one stored procedure and not both.
Is there a way to use and run at once multiple procedures?

Comment: The underlying mysql drivers do not allow multiple queries to be issued in a single query call. It's a safety measure to prevent some forms of SQL injection. This still applies even though you're using PDO.

Comment: Really, the best course of action if they must be run together, is to create another procedure which calls both of them inside a transaction itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One query can run only one storedProcedure.

If you still need to run only one query, I recommend you to write another storedProcedure, that calls them one after another.